# redirectUrl from web to app in real device

Tags: react-native, spotify

I'm developing an android app with react native and use react-native-auth-app. I code on Windows laptop and run on real device using ADB USB cable. My use case is: user login my app using Spotify Website authorization (i'm using Spotify API), and when it successfully, it will redirect to my app. This is my problem: How can i define my redirectUrl to config in Dashboard Spotify API and in my code ? Please help me, thanks to all.

Notes:

- I've tried using IPv4 address (ipconfig /all on my laptop) + 5037, and nothing happened on authorize website.
- Of course, nothing happened when i used localhost + 5037 or 8081

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume redirect URI is `my-awesome-app://auth-callback`.

1. Add `my-awesome-app://auth-callback` to *Redirect URIs* in [App settings](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/apps)
2. Add `my-awesome-app` as *appAuthRedirectScheme* property to [defaultConfig](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#android-setup)